# Do Grothendieck topoi with enough points satisfy the fan theorem internally?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, topos-theory, constructive-mathematics

Fourman and Hylland proved in the 80s that all spatial topoi satisfy the full fan theorem internally, while there are examples of localic topoi that do not satisfy it.

This leads one to conjecture a straightforward generalization: the spatial topoi are exactly the localic topoi with enough points. Do general grothendieck topoi with enough points satisfy the fan theorem? Or is there a counterexample that has enough points but does not satisfy the fan theorem?

Comment: Maybe you should give a reference or a statement of the precise result proved by Fourman and Hyland and a more precise statement for what you mean by "satisfies the fan theorem". I believe some version of your question should follow formally from the result of Fourman and Hyland, but without more details I can't say anything.

Comment: They proved that the internal Cantor space is (cover) compact

Comment: Where "internal" here means specifically "interpreted using the Kripke-Joyal semantics of sheaves over a topological space".

Comment: Can you provide a reference? I still need more details - typically to know how the étale cover witnessing the existence of the internal finite cover is obtained.

Comment: @SimonHenry This is the springer monograph: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0061823

the doi is https://doi.org/10.1007/BFb0061823